# Pipe logs to csv in bash script

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu-14.04, pipeline

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed with the task of piping log file contents to a csv file based on certain criteria.
Essentially, the problem is something like this:

> Write a script that receives http logs (or any arbitrary .log file) via pipe 
>       input, and outputs a summarized csv in the number of hits per url per day.
>
> Example: executing the pipe command

```
cat access.log|some filter commands|./your_script > summary.csv
```

> creates a text file called summary.csv with the content:
>
> " Action and path. 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02. 2015-01-03
>
> GET /index.php, 34, 53, 65
>
> POST /administrator, 32, 59, 39
>
> ..."
>
> and so forth.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is figuring out how to identify and execute specific parts of the pipe input command, and apply filters, before feeding it to the output pipe. 
From what I'm familiar with, an array of command parameters (such as "cat", "gedit", ">", "|", etc) might work, but this leaves the problem of identifying them and executing them as a pipe command would, instead of just one after the other.

I've searched quite thoroughly, but as yet found nothing even remotely helpful, aside from the suggestion to divide the pipe command into separate instructions and execute them one by one.
If anyone can suggest an easier and more effective way to do this, or any advice on this particular problem, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `aside from the suggestion to divide the pipe command into separate instructions and execute them one by one`. Yes, that really is the best way. Until you understand how the individual commands work, this is the best way to learn the linux/unix philosophy of "small tools that do one thing well" (connected by pipes) ;-) .... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need `tee` command. You can use it to "fork the pipe", which means that an output 
file could be created after a specific pipe input command. It is very useful when looking for errors.
For example:

```
cat access.log | some filter commands | tee out01.txt \
| some other filter | tee ou02.txt | ./your_script > summary.csv
```

More examples [here](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/tee-command-linux/).

Comment: `tee` can be helpful too, but then you have to manage looking at the files. Per my comment above, slice and dice your command can be easy to learn with. Make an `access.log` file that has just 2 records in it, 1 of the type you want to look at, and the other, a record that you want to ignore. Then you can see the effect of multiple pipelines on one screen. Good luck to all.